# How can you filter a Django query's joined tables then iterate the joined tables in one query?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have table Parent, and a table Child with a foreign key to table Parent.

I want to run a query for all Parents with a child called Eric, and report Eric's age.

I run:

```
parents = Parents.objects.filter(child__name='Eric')
```

I then iterate over the queryset:

```
for parent in parents:
    print(f'Parent name {parent.name} child Eric age {parent.child.age}')
```

Clearly this doesn't work - I need to access child through the foreign key object manager, so I try:

```
for parent in parents:
    print(f'Parent name {parent.name}')
    for child in parent.child_set.all():
        print(f'Child Eric age {parent.child.age}')
```

Django returns all children's ages, not just children named Eric.

I can repeat the filter conditions:

```
parents = Parents.objects.filter(child__name='Eric')
for parent in parents:
    print(f'Parent name {parent.name}')
    for child in parent.child_set.filter(name='Eric'):
        print(f'Child Eric age {child.age}')
```

But this means duplicate code (so risks future inconsistency when another dev makes a change to one not the other), and runs a second query on the database.

Is there a way of getting the matching records and iterating over them? Been Djangoing for years and can't believe I can't do this!

PS. I know that I can do `Child.objects.filter(name='Eric').select_related('parent')`. But what I would really like to do involves a second child table. So add to the above example a table Address with a foreign key to Parent. I want to get parents with children named Eric and addresses in Timbuktu and iterate over the all Timbuktu addresses and all little Erics. This is why I don't want to use Child's object manager.

This is the best I could come up with - three queries, repeating each filter.

```
children = Children.objects.filter(name='Eric')
addresses = Address.objects.filter(town='Timbuktu')
parents=(
    Parent.objects
        .filter(child__name='Eric', address__town='Timbuktu')
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch('child_set', children))
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch('address_set', addresses))
)
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate over parents that do not have a matching child?

Comment: Good question - I'll update the question - no. I also just realized I need to justify why I'm using the Parent object manager and not Child's.

Comment: Do you only want to iterate over the `Child` table? Your `Address` example could be solved with a subquery `Child.objects.filter(name='Eric', parent__in=Parent.objects.filter(address__country='Timbuktu')).select_related('parent')`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need a single query? You could use `prefetch_related` and only perform 2

Comment: I want to iterate over all addresses in Timbuktu and all children called Eric. Happy to run two queries, or however many is the least I can get away with.

Comment: I experimented with `Prefetch()` and got it to three queries, and repeating each filter.

Comment: And you want to avoid repeated code? 3 queries does not seem excessive

Comment: You deserve some credit for your patience then, I'll post the three query solution in the question, but if you post it I'll mark yours the answer and delete mine. In the misty past I used to write SQL, when this would be one query, one recordset and one loop, so thought I must be overlooking some simple way with the Django ORM.

Comment: To be fair, I think you could use a `values()` queryset to get all of the data you need in 1 query. The only issue is that then you would have repeated data and your logic to de-duplicate and iterate would be a little messy, although the repeated query solution is not "clean"

Comment: Thank you! `.values('name', 'child__age', 'address__whatever')` seems to work well, and in my case is cleaner than nested for loops over prefetched recordsets and repeated filter definitions, and more efficient. Also really lovely, basic Django code.

Comment: Thoughts fwiw.. The listing of fields is verbose, and be sure to use `order_by` if you're looping and generating some nested structure from the output. I assume memory usage isn't nasty as all duplicates will reference the same string object in memory but haven't tested - I'll try to remember to post here if that comes back to haunt me.

Answer (score 0):

The `.values` function gives you direct access to the recordset returned (thank you @Iain Shelvington):

```
parents_queryset_dicts = Parent.objects
    .filter(child__name='Eric', address__town='Timbuktu')
    .values('id', 'name', 'child__id', 'address__id', 'child__age', 'address__whatever')
    .order_by('id', 'child__id', 'address__id')
```

Note though that this retrieves a Cartesian product of children and addresses, so our gain in reduced query count is slightly offset by double-sized result sets and de-duplication below. So I am starting to think two queries using `Child.objects` and `Address.objects` is superior - slightly slower but simpler code.

In my actual use case I have multiple, multi-table chains of foreign key joins, so am splitting the query to prevent the Cartesian join, but still making use of the `.values()` approach to get filtered, nested tables.

If you then want a hierarchical structure, eg, for sending as JSON to the client, to produce:

```
parents = {
    parent_id: {
        'name': name, 
        'children': {
            child_id: {
                'age': child_age
            },
        'addresses': {
            address_id: {
                'whatever': address_whatever
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Run something like:

```
prev_parent_id = prev_child_id = prev_address_id = None
parents = {}
for parent in parents_queryset_dicts:
    if parent['id'] != prev_parent_id:
        parents[parent['id']] = {'name': parent['name'], children: {}, addresses: {}}
        prev_parent_id = parent['id']
    if parent['child__id'] != prev_child_id:
        parents[parent['id']]['children'][parent['child__id']] = {'age': parent['child__age']}
        prev_child_id = parent['child__id']
    if parent['address__id'] != prev_address_id:
        parents[parent['id']]['addresses'][parent['address__id']] = {'whatever': parent['address__whatever']}
        prev_address_id = parent['address__id']
```

This is dense code, and you no longer get access to any fields not explicitly extracted and copied in, including any nested `~_set` querysets, and de-duplication of the Cartesian product is not obvious to later developers. You can grab the queryset, keep it, then extract the `.values`, so you have both from the same, single, database query. But often the three query repeated filters is a bit cleaner, if a couple database queries less efficient:

```
children = Children.objects.filter(name='Eric')
addresses = Address.objects.filter(town='Timbuktu')
parents_queryset = (
    Parent.objects
        .filter(child__name='Eric', address__town='Timbuktu')
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch('child_set', children))
        .prefetch_related(Prefetch('address_set', addresses))
)

parents = {}
for parent in parents_queryset:
    parents[parent.id] = {'name': parent['name'], children: {}, addresses: {}}
    for child in parent.child_set:  # this is implicitly filtered
        parents[parent.id]['children'][child.id] = {'age': child.age}
    for address in parent.address_set:  # also implicitly filtered
        parents[parent.id]['addresses'][address.id] = {'whatever': address.whatever}
```

One last approach, which someone briefly posted then deleted - I'd love to know why - is using `annotate` and `F()` objects. I have not experimented with this, the SQL generated looks fine though and it seems to run a single query and not require repeating filters:

```
from django.db.models import F
parents = (
    Parent.objects.filter(child__name='Eric')
    .annotate(child_age=F('child__age'))
)
```

Pros and cons seem identical to `.values()` above, although `.values()` seems slightly more basic Django (so easier to read) and you don't have to duplicate field names (eg, with the obfuscation above of `child_age=child__age`). Advantages might be convenience of `.` accessors instead of `['field']`, you keep hold of the lazy nested recordsets, etc. - although if you're counting the queries you probably want things to fall over if you issue an accidental query per row.